# Traefik Path Based Routing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have two backends I want to serve from one Host. One from host.domain.com and the other from host.domain.com/path. The first frontend rule is straightforward: `Host:host.domain.com`.

The second is giving me some trouble. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines) I believe I should be using `Host:host.domain.com;PathPrefixStrip:/path`. This returns a 200 on host.domain.com/path, but when I click the link to somepage.html, it sends me to host.domain.com/somepage.html, so it returns a 404. If I go directly to host.domain.com/path/somepage.html it returns a 200. The link to somepage.html behaves correctly when I go directly to host.domain.com/path/index.html.

Are my assumptions/interpretations of the documentation incorrect or is this not an issue with Traefik at all?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really specific to traefik, any virtual path based reverse proxy that doesn't rewrite the contents of the web page returned (and few do this) have problems when the contents of that web page have absolute paths. The web page needs to either know about the "/path" and modify all the links it gives you, or use relative links, without a leading "/". This should be fixed within your website, web application, or hopefully a configuration for a web application. Depending on the application, once reconfigured, you may need to adjust the traefik rule to just "PathPrefix" instead of "PathPrefixStrip".

Comment: Sphinx already compiles anchors with relative paths: `<a class="reference internal" href="somepage.html">Some Page</a>`. The thing that's throwing me off is that when I hit host.domain.com/path/index.html directly, the link to somepage.html behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `PathPrefix` instead a `PathPrefixStrip` . The *Strip* rules remove the path before presenting it to the backend.

> Since the path is stripped prior to forwarding, your backend is expected to listen on /.

Comment: The backend is listening on /. I assume that's why host.domain.com/path works. Using `PathPrefix` returns a 404 at host.domain.com/path and host.domain.com/path/somepage.html.